# Reset password link - User id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I create a link to reset a user password like this :

```
https://localhost:5001/ResetPassword?id=a33183db-f7f6-45aa-b8dc-7fe101e04682&token=CfDJ8KXvGzIVoh9Knrlx
```

id is the user id (`[dbo].[AspNetUsers].[Id]`) and token is the result of `UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync`

Is there a security risk to put the user id directly in the url? Is it disadvised?

Comment: A similar question was asked here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string

Comment: An id has no meaning in and of itself. It needs *context*, such as a database table to give it meaning. If a malicious user can view your database table, you have far more pressing issues than exposing ids.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your requirements and what you consider secure. In 99% application passing a random (looking) GUID in a link will not give any information to the external attacker. Unless somewhere in your application you have a page that shows user information based on ID (i.e. http://localhost/users/{id} ). But that can be counted as a vulnerability in itself (though depends on application).

So in this case I would say there is no major issue with giving out an ID. However if you are very paranoid, you can omit the ID and only pass a token in the link. Then on password reset page you can ask for an email again, get userID from that email and proceed with password reset.